# Options.Applicative, (<>) and the Monoid type class

Tags: haskell

I am learning about Haskell. I am importing the `Options.Applicative` module, like so:

```
import Options.Applicative ((<>), Parser)
import qualified Options.Applicative as P
```

However, this returns

```
Module ‘Options.Applicative’ does not export ‘(<>)’
```

What is wrong with this? This [documentation](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/optparse-applicative) suggests this should be possible.

Comment: The documentation only says that you can *use* `<>`; it doesn't say that you can import it from `Options.Applicative`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to import `(<>)` from either `Data.Monoid` or `Data.Semigroup`, as [`Options.Applicative` doesn't actually re-export it](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/optparse-applicative-0.13.0.0/docs/Options-Applicative.html). A quick way to verify that is checking [the "<" page in the documentation index](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/optparse-applicative-0.13.0.0/docs/doc-index-60.html), which would include `(<>)` if it was re-exported.

P.S.: While the readme currently on Hackage is slightly misleading indeed, the missing import was already [added upstream at GitHub](https://github.com/pcapriotti/optparse-applicative/commit/23f15d262fede5a3a0fe9c25808719b811275df0#diff-04c6e90faac2675aa89e2176d2eec7d8), and so it will be fixed when the next version of the package is released.

Answer (score 7):

`(<>)` is in [Data.Monoid](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Data-Monoid.html#v:-60--62-), not Options.Applicative. It's an infix synonym for `mappend`.